# Generating all possible k-regular matrices given n nodes

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

so I'm trying to create a graph with n nodes, where each node is connected to k other nodes. Let's use the example of n=6, k=3. According to this page at GENREG, (which has set out to find all the possible k-regular graphs given a certain number of nodes) there are two distinct nonisomorphic graphs that are regular and connected. However, the graphs I've generated does not look like an isomorphism of either of the 2 graphs seen on that page (this is the link: http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/REGGRAPHS/06_3_3.html) because they cannot be rotated to look like those graphs. It would be great if you could tell me what I'm missing, and ultimately, how to generate all the possible adjacency matrices for the type of graph I'm looking for (i.e. all possible permutations).

[generated graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MzMw.png)

Comment: It is isomorphic to graph $1$. Assume the vertices in graph $1$ is named as $1,2,3,4,5,6$ clock-wisely. You can randomly name a vertice $1$ in the generated graph, and then name one of its neighbor $2$. Then you assume it is isomorphic to one of the graphs. Then you can play a logic game (like see which vertice connects both $v_1$ and $v_2$ to label one more). And see if you get a contradiction or not. You can also do this to show that the two graphs are not isomorphic. A more interesting problem is to prove that there are only two nonisomorphic graphs, and see if there are patterns.

Comment: FYI, http://imgur.com/dsCylHP

Comment: Oh ok thanks, that makes sense. Is there a formula for the total number of labelled graphs, if I already have the two separate isomorphism?

Comment: I am not sure about that. But I guess that both questions, i.e., finding total number of labelled graph and number of non-isomorphic graphs, are not that easy (especially for large $k,n$ since you cannot guarantee connectivity).

Comment: Why couldn't you just keep one node fixed, and permute the other nodes to get (n-1)! automorphisms? Is that over counting or undercounting?